# Facet function in highcharts

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-highcharter

I have a data like this example:

```
df <-
  data.frame(
    date = seq(as.Date("2015-01-01"), as.Date("2015-12-31"), 100),
    id = rep(LETTERS, each = 4)[1:100],
    replicate(2, sample(1001, 100))
  )
```

Plotting with ggplot is Ok

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = date)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = X1)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = X2), linetype = 2) +
  facet_wrap( ~ id , scales = "free")
```

I found some info about facet implementation in highchart
[higcharter-grid-test](http://rpubs.com/jbkunst/higcharter-grid-test)
and I tried to plot it with highchart in order to make an interactive plot, but `highchart::hw_grid()` and `browsable()` are deprecated. Can anybody help me with ploting my data?

My snippet :

```
  highchart() %>% 
    hc_add_series(name = "X1", data = df$X1) %>% 
    hc_add_series(name = "X2", data = df$X2) %>% 
    hw_grid(id, rowheight = 200, ncol = 3)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`hw_grid` and `browsable` approach seems to work still for me.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(highcharter)

# Create data
df <-
  data.frame(
    date = seq(as.Date("2015-01-01"), as.Date("2015-12-31"), 100),
    id = rep(LETTERS, each = 4)[1:100],
    replicate(2, sample(1001, 100))
  )

# Reshape long format
df_long <-
  df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c("X1", "X2"))

# Check
head(df_long, 12)

#> # A tibble: 12 x 4
#>    date       id    name  value
#>    <date>     <chr> <chr> <int>
#>  1 2015-01-01 A     X1      490
#>  2 2015-01-01 A     X2      868
#>  3 2015-04-11 A     X1      422
#>  4 2015-04-11 A     X2      751
#>  5 2015-07-20 A     X1      958
#>  6 2015-07-20 A     X2       52
#>  7 2015-10-28 A     X1      486
#>  8 2015-10-28 A     X2      680
#>  9 2015-01-01 B     X1      631
#> 10 2015-01-01 B     X2      425
#> 11 2015-04-11 B     X1      532
#> 12 2015-04-11 B     X2      402
```

### Now highcharter

Iterate plotting code over each letter, storing outputs in a list

```r
list_of_plots <- map(LETTERS, function(x) {
  
  filtered <-
    df_long %>%
    filter(id == x)

  highchart() %>%
    hc_add_series(data = filtered,
                  hcaes(x = date, y = value, group = name),
                  type = "line") %>%
    hc_title(text = x)   
  
  })

# Then pass final list to `hw_grid` function.

hw_grid(list_of_plots, rowheight = 300) %>%
  htmltools::browsable()
```

Here's (some of) the output:

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-03-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>